Problem with Astro Auth. with Google OAuth
I am making a web application with Astro and at the same time using astro auth for authentication. I use Google as a provider, but when I click on the signIn button:
VM4243:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetchStack')
at _0xa4a750.<computed>.<computed>.<computed> [as json] (eval at <anonymous> (index.astro:28:12766), <anonymous>:1:41898)
at async signIn (client.ts:64:15)

<Layout title="Home page">
  <div class="h-screen">
    <button id="login">Login</button>
    <button id="logout">Logout</button>
    <script>
      const { signIn, signOut } = await import("auth-astro/client");
      document.querySelector("#login").onclick = () => signIn("google");
      document.querySelector("#logout").onclick = () => signOut();
    </script>
  </div>
</Layout>


please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
